# UPDATE apenas nas últimas linhas inseridas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-update

Estou importando algumas planilhas Excel via ETL para um banco relacional. O problema é que para que eu consiga realizar o relacionamento das tabelas, estou usando consultas para a inserção das chaves estrangeiras. Porém, conforme o banco cresce, essas consultas estão levando um tempo absurdamente grande.
Existe alguma forma de realizar um UPDATE apenas nos últimos registros que foram incluídos? Por exemplo:

```
UPDATE estrutura q
SET q.id_horizonte = (SELECT h.id_horizonte FROM horizonte h 
WHERE q.observacao = h.observacao AND q.nome_horizonte = h.nome_horizonte AND q.amostra_codigo = h.amostra_codigo)
LIMIT 50
```

Não está funcionando dessa forma, mas a minha pergunta é justamente essa: existe alguma maneira para que esse UPDATE não seja aplicado em todos os registros da tabela e só nos últimos 50 incluídos? Isso ajudaria muito com o desempenho das consultas.

Answer (score 2):

Experimente

```
UPDATE estrutura q
SET q.id_horizonte = 
(SELECT h.id_horizonte 
FROM horizonte h
WHERE q.observacao = h.observacao 
AND q.nome_horizonte = h.nome_horizonte 
AND q.amostra_codigo = h.amostra_codigo) 
WHERE q.id_horizonte  
IN 
(SELECT id_horizonte 
FROM estrutura 
ORDER BY id_horizonte DESC Limit 50)
```

Comment: Oi Mauro, recebi o seguinte erro: #1235 - Esta versão de MySQL não suporta ainda 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver colocando uma condição simples no meu UPDATE. No meu caso funcionou porque os campos que eu quero atualizar estão sempre nulos.

```
UPDATE estrutura q
SET q.id_horizonte = (SELECT h.id_horizonte FROM horizonte h 
WHERE q.observacao = h.observacao AND q.nome_horizonte = h.nome_horizonte AND q.amostra_codigo = h.amostra_codigo)
WHERE id_horizonte IS NULL
```